# Can I make use of my wife's Capital Gains Tax Allowance for gains under an EMI Share Option scheme?

Tags: united-kingdom, capital-gains-tax, employee-stock-options, option-exercise

My employer has granted me a number of share options under an EMI scheme.  They also partnered with their brokers to allow us to exercise these options without needing to put up-front capital in to purchase the shares, instead the brokers would buy and sell them, keeping a small fee for doing so.  Shortly before the end of the 2020/21 tax year, I made use of this facility to exercise a portion of my options. I owed income tax and national insurance on part of the profit, which my employer took care of in a normal PAYE pay slip.  The remainder of the profit is a capital gain. The proceeds were paid to me in full into a joint account with my wife, leaving me to take care of the capital gains tax in my usual annual tax return.

This capital gain is higher than the 2020/21 personal allowance of £12,300, but less than twice that.  With no other capital gains during the year, is there a way to also use my wife's personal allowance?  If so, how should that be reported?

If it makes a difference, within days of receiving the money, a large portion was spent on a car in my wife's name, paid for from the same joint account - would using the money from the joint account here count as a gift?

Comment: Why do you think you owe CGT at all, if the shares were sold immediately and you were taxed on the option value via PAYE?

Comment: I thought the gain from selling the shares is what would trigger it?  The income/PAYE was taxed on the difference between the grant price and exercise price, which were lower than the actual price of the shares.

Comment: You should owe CGT on any gain between what you sold the shares for and what you already paid for through PAYE. If they were sold immediately wouldn't that be negligible?

Comment: I essentially paid zero, the upfront capital was provided by the brokers who bought and sold on my behalf, passing the remaining capital to my employer.  They then held back what was needed to pay the PAYE tax on the difference between grant and exercise price, and passed on the rest to me, with the stipulation that I was responsible for reporting and paying CGT on it.

Comment: Let's say you had one option with an grant price of £1, the stock value when you exercised was £2.50, and you ultimately sold for say £2.51 because of market moves in that short period. Your broker lent you £1 temporarily to exercise which went to your employer, you should have been taxed on £1.50 via PAYE, and you owe CGT on 1p. At least in my understanding, I've never dealt with this before. If you owed CGT on any more than 1p, that would be double taxation, which while not unheard of is not normally expected in this situation.

Comment: Ah - that's where the difference is.  It's more like a grant price of £1, an exercise price of £1.20 and the stock on the day being worth £2, so the PAYE tax was on the 20p difference, with the CGT coming from the rest.

Comment: I'm a bit confused by how the £1.20 was determined then. Did the market move very suddenly after they were exercised? Or is it that you became entitled to exercise the options some time ago when the share price was actually £1.20, but delayed exercising them until now?

Comment: Ah sorry, yes - I’ve held these options for several years, the exercise price was set then.

Comment: I've edited your question in a way that would have reduced my confusion, please feel free to edit further if it's not correct/clear to you.

Comment: @GS-ApologisetoMonica The stock value at the point the option is exercised is not relevant. The capital gain arises from the difference between the option price and the sale price.

Comment: @SteveKidd so where did the PAYE liability come from? I'm still a bit confused about the exact details here but they aren't actually necessary to answer the question.

Comment: @GS-ApologisetoMonica It’s part of the EMI structure, you have to pay income tax / NI on the difference between grant price and exercise price, but not until you actually exercise the options, as opposed to having any liabilities at the point of the granting.

Comment: @GS-ApologisetoMonica There is an Income Tax and National Insurance (PAYE) liability **if** the option price was at a discount to the market price at the point the options were granted. Some info can be found at https://www.gov.uk/tax-employee-share-schemes/enterprise-management-incentives-emis

Comment: Ahh, I get it now. So the "exercise price" is the market price at the time of grant. Thanks.

Comment: @GS-ApologisetoMonica right - I guess the terms “grant price” and “exercise price” might be specific to my options offer, and not actually be widely used.

Answer (score 3):

This is not an expert answer as I'm not personally familiar with the ins and outs of CGT, but I think it's probably too late now. You can transfer assets like shares to your spouse freely without changing the so-called "cost basis" of the shares, so if you had done that with half of them before selling them, you would each have owed CGT on your own halves. But as you sold them, you owe the CGT.

Comment: Right, that makes sense.  I think next time the opportunity comes I might see if the brokers can buy/sell enough to then cover buying more, and transferring those shares to me - will remove the need for the capital, but allows for more options with what to do with the resulting shares themselves.

Answer (score 1):

For the future, you would need to dispose of (sell or simply gift) half the shares to your wife between the option being exercised and the shares being sold.

But perhaps you don't need to do a broker-driven sale half the shares to your wife. Perhaps you could simply gift half the shares in trust to your wife (i.e. you would hold half the shares on trust for your wife). This counts as a disposal at no gain and no loss. You need not even tell the broker (just a one page trust deed). Then your broker would sell all the shares, yours, plus your wife's (with you as trustee). Half the gain would be attributed to you, and half to your wife (who would have inherited your base price). Indeed you could construct a trust deed such that half the proceeds of all future vestings were to be held in trust by you for your wife, which would then achieve that automatically. You might want a lawyer to draw that up in case HMRC ever asked for evidence (unlikely).

There are a large number of confused comments about why there is any CGT to pay. Under UK law, for qualifying EMI options (unlike normal options), in most circumstances:

- The difference between the exercise (strike) price and the market value at the time of grant is taxed as income, at the time of exercise. IE the tax on the grant of options at an undervalue is paid at exercise.
- Upon exercise, the base price for CGT purposes is the market value at the time of grant (not the market value at the time of exercise). This means an immediate disposal may well yield a substantial capital gain (which is more favourable than a charge to income tax).

What one would normally do for CGT purposes would be to transfer half the assets (here EMI options) *now* to your wife. But you cannot do that firstly because the EMI option contract almost certainly prevents it, and secondly even if it did not, the EMI options would cease to be qualifying (one likely reason being that your wife presumably does not work for the same employer). This is why you would need to make the transfer between exercise and sale.

You should however check there are no other restrictions on transferring shares between you and your wife. For instance, your company may have an insider trading policy that restricts this to certain periods.